# Wordpress: Custom search result page throws 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I have followed the link [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) in codex and created the following

This is my searchform.php

```
<form action="/search" method="get" role="search" id="searchform">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="s" id="search" class="form-control search-bar" placeholder="Search Healthkart Blog" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
        <div class="input-group-append button-icon">
            <button class="btn" type="button" id="searchBtn">
                <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/search-icon.png" alt="search" class="search-icon-white">
                <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/search-icon-grey.png" alt="search" class="search-icon-grey">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have included it in header.php as

```
get_search_form();
```

And the JS for submitting the form in this way

```
$("#searchBtn").click(function(){
    $("#searchform").submit();
})
```

I have also created a custom search result page called search.php and it contains the normal search page code. Then I have created a page in wordpress pages called search (URL as /search) and assigned the custom search result template to it.

The issue is when I submit the form, it gets redirected to /search/?s=test123 and returns a 404 page. But if I hit the urls /search/test123, it works.

How do I make the search form submit to the URL /search/test123 ?

Comment: Should the backslash be in here `action="/search"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make the search form submit to the URL /search/test123 ?

You can add :

```
$("#searchform").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $("#searchform").attr('action') +'/'+ $("#searchform #search").val();
});
```

But with this solution, browser without JavaScript won't work.

To fix it, you can add the following to the search template:

```
if (isset($_GET['s']) && !empty($_GET['s'])) {
    wp_redirect(get_permalink() . $_GET['s'], 301);
    die();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by browser without javascript? I did not get it why the redirect is added in the search template. if the template is opened then its proper, we dont need to redirect

Comment: You can disable it in the settings, and by default TorBrowser has it disabled. Some society/institutes also disabled it for some security reason.